# Pervasive SQL Server configuration

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, performance, raid

Our Sage 50 application takes a long time to load. We recently moved it to a newer server and the speed has improved but opening the application and accessing data is still time consuming and not acceptable to the company owner. Takes about 3-5 minutes.

His computer is a Core i7, 256GB SSD, 8GB memory and GbE connection. File transfers to our file server is quick so I don't see anything that could be slowing things down on his computer. The application will open fairly quick if no company data is selected.

Our current Sage server runs a RAID 1 on WD Raptors, SATA2. Server has about 8-10 connections for the Sage application and another 6-7 users for another application that also runs a DB on it for engineering. Watching the network monitor, network usage seems low. Drive access is 50% or higher at all times. CPU is about 20-30%. Memory used is around 2.72GB jumping to 3-3.3GB.

What are some things I can do to diagnose the slow speed? Could it be the hard drives on the server? What RAID setup would be recommended, 1, 5, 10?

Budget is allowed to use SSD's as cache if required. We currently use Adaptec cards for our other servers. Not sure which card is used for this one as it was a prior purchase from Dell.

Client runs Windows 7 Pro x64
Server runs Windows Server 2008 R2

Comment: I am troubleshooting a similar issue at a small company that has Sage 50 installed in a client/server configuration on a small number of HP ProDesk 600 G3 mini PCs with Intel Core i5-7500T processors and solid state drives.  Sage 50 is slow to load even on the server computer.  Did you ever determine a solution?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to diagnose this kind of issue over the web... there's just so many things that can be a factor. But I did spot two items in the question worth highlighting:

> Drive access is 50% or higher at all times.

and

> Our current Sage server runs a RAID 1 on WD Raptors, SATA2

This indicates that you might be able to improve throughput by going to RAID 10 with higher-speed SAS disks, or by using SSDs (or both RAID 10 and SSDs).

But again, this is really just a guess until you can do some real profiling.

Comment: What are some tests I can do on the client PC to verify everything is okay?

What other tests on the server can I do to see where the bottlenecks are?

Comment: Definitely *sounds like* an I/O bottleneck.  You're going to have to start profiling to nail it down, though.

Comment: We tested with 1 user, and it loaded instantly to the login screen. After the 4th user logs in, performance becomes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had an instance of Sage that was would take several minutes to load at startup.  Long story short, it turned out to be a SQL Server Stored procedure that was the problem.  The SP had to do with reoccurring payment schedules. It ran on startup and when the user went to the reoccurring payments screen. There is a toggle setting to turn off the SP on startup.  The delay on the reoccurring payments screen got so bad that I had to rewrite the SP (got no support from Sage).  Instead of using set operations, their SP when itteravely over the entire dataset.

If you have a lot of reoccurring payments, then this may be the problem.  Otherwise, I suggest you run a SQL Server trace to see if any other Stored Procedures are taking a long time.

Comment: How do I perform this? And we do not have any recocurring payments.

Comment: @Edwin The US edition of Sage 50 uses Pervasive PSQL and not SQL Server.  Which Sage product were you using?